# Why am I seeing a one-off error with Math.pow(11, 16)?

Tags: java, pow

I have to compute 11^16 for a project at my Uni. Somehow `Math.pow(11,16)` computes a solution exactly 1 less than WolframAlpha or my other computation method.

[image: Result from WolframAlpha]

My code is:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long a = 11;
        long b = 16;
        System.out.println("" + (long)Math.pow(a, b));
        System.out.println("" + squareAndMultiply(a, b));
    }

    public static long squareAndMultiply(long b, long e){
        long result = 1;
        long sq = b;
        while(e>0){
            if(e%2==1){
                result *= sq;
            }
            sq = sq * sq;
            e /= 2;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The result from the code is:

math.pow(11,16):

> 45949729863572160

squareAndMultiply(11,16):

> 45949729863572161

Comment: What does it tell you that you had to **cast** the result of `Math.pow` to a long?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With floating-point arithmetic, you're in that gray zone where the precision of a `double` is less than that of a `long` (even if the *range* of a `double` is much bigger).

A `double` has 53 bits of precision, whereas a `long` can devote all 64 bits to precision.  When you're dealing with values as high as 11<sup>16</sup>, the difference between one `double` value and the next one up becomes noticeable.

Java has a [built-in method `Math.ulp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(double)) ("unit in last place") that effectively gives the difference in values between consecutive representable values.  (There's a `double` version and a `float` version.)

```
System.out.println(Math.ulp(Math.pow(11, 16)));
```

> 8.0

That means the least possible `double` value greater than `45949729863572160` is `45949729863572168`.

The long value `45949729863572161` is correct, but the value you're getting with `Math.pow`, `45949729863572160`, is as close as a `double` can get to the true answer, given its limited (but still large) precision.

Casting to a `long` makes no difference, because `Math.pow` already computes the result as a `double`, so the answer is off by one already.  Your `long` method of computing the value is correct.

If you're computing values that would overflow `long`, then instead of using `double`, you can use [`BigDecimal`, which has its own `pow` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow(int)) to retain a precision of 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of this discrepancy is loss of precision because of Double precision numbers are accurate up to sixteen decimal places.

One way to demonstrate is this example.

```
System.out.println((double)999999999999999999L);
```

outputs:

```
1.0E18
```

The output of `Math.pow(11, 16)` is `4.594972986357216E16`, which on casting to long gets converted into `45949729863572160`.

If you are interested more in learning about the loss of precision, you can check [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=double%20precision%20number%20of%20places%20of%20precision).

Comment: `double` only has [a maximum of sixteen digits of precision](https://www.google.com/search?q=double+precision+number+of+places+of+precision) anyway.  There's no loss of precision during the cast.  See https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/MushyDeterminedCharacterencoding#Main.java

Comment: You are right. I ran the same program for 11^15 and got accurate numbers. 4.177248169415651E15
4177248169415651

Thanks for pointing it out. I will update my answer.